# How to parse a string from servlet to javascript and created a formatted object which contains array values

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json, parsing

I have managed to create below string and pass it to jsp

```
"Dataset1:[ 10,22,33,44,55,66,7 ],Dataset2:[ 20,12,43,24,55,26,47 ],Dataset3:[ 30,12,53,64,5,16,77 ],Dataset4:[4 0,12,63,64,5,6,44 ]"
```

My chart function accepts data as js object described below

```
var graph_dataset = {
                "Dataset1":[10,22,33,44,55,66,7  ]
                ,"Dataset2":[20,12,43,24,55,26,47  ]
                ,"Dataset3":[30,12,53,64,5,16,77  ]
                ,"Dataset4":[40,12,63,64,5,6,44  ]
            };
```

so that I should be able to get my array (value corresponding to each key) if I call it by `graph_dataset.Dataset4`.

I have tried lot of things by hit and trail including JSON.parse. Please help with a piece of code

Comment: it would be easier if passed a json string to the jsp, "{Dataset1:[ 10,22,33,44,55,66,7 ],Dataset2:[ 20,12,43,24,55,26,47 ] ... }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes me feel dirty but it gets the job done.

```js
let str = "Dataset1:[ 10,22,33,44,55,66,7 ],Dataset2:[ 20,12,43,24,55,26,47 ],Dataset3:[ 30,12,53,64,5,16,77 ],Dataset4:[40,12,63,64,5,6,44 ]";
let result = str.split(',Dataset');
result[0] = result[0].split('Dataset')[1];

let obj = result.reduce( (prev, curr) => {
    let ar = curr.split(':');
    prev['Dataset' + ar[0]] = JSON.parse(ar[1]);
    return prev;
}, {} );

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Will, for answering.. I later managed to correctly form script the string like below
 var str='{"Dataset1":[10,22,33,44,55,66,7],"Dataset2":[20,12,43,24,55,26,47],"Dataset3":[30,12,53,64,5,16,77]}';

 and below command is working perfectly now
var graph_thread_minutes=JSON.parse(str);


Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Answering for someone who is facing similar difficulty.

I corrected the string formatting and added `quotes` and `{}` wherever applicable.

After correct formatting string looks like 
`var str='{"Dataset1":[10,22,33,44,55,66,7],"Dataset2":[20,12,43,24,55,26,47],"Dataset3":[30,12,53,64,5,16,77]}';`

I am able to parse the string and generate graph out of it successfully.

```
obj=JSON.parse(str);
```